# Finding the image file name and renaming with parent folder names

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, batch-rename

I have this file structure. I wanted to use the image filename appended with the parent folder names.

**Before:**

```
├── ak
│   ├── adak
│   │   ├── Hello\ World456
│   │   ├── cup-printing
│   │   │   └── Tshirt-printing.jpg
│   │   ├── hello-\ world789
│   │   ├── hello-world79
│   │   └── tshirt\ printing
│   │       └── Tshirt-printing.jpg
│   ├── akhiok
│   │   ├── Hello\ World456
│   │   ├── cup-printing
│   │   │   └── Tshirt-printing.jpg
│   │   ├── hello-\ world789
│   │   ├── hello-world79
│   │   └── tshirt\ printing
│   │       └── Tshirt-printing.jpg
```

Here parent folder names are ak, adak.

Ak= state name
Adak = city name.

After it should be like this..

**After:**

```
├── ak
│   ├── adak
│   │   ├── Hello\ World456
│   │   ├── cup-printing
│   │   │   └── Tshirt-printing-adak-ak.jpg
│   │   ├── hello-\ world789
│   │   ├── hello-world79
│   │   └── tshirt\ printing
│   │       └── Tshirt-printing-adak-ak.jpg
│   ├── akhiok
│   │   ├── Hello\ World456
│   │   ├── cup-printing
│   │   │   └── Tshirt-printing-akhiok-ak.jpg
│   │   ├── hello-\ world789
│   │   ├── hello-world79
│   │   └── tshirt\ printing
│   │       └── Tshirt-printing-akhiok-ak.jpg
```

Bash command can help over here?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -exec sh -c '
  suffix=$(printf "%s" "$1" | awk -F"/" "{for(i=NF-2;i>1;i--)printf \"-\"\$i;}");
  echo mv "$1" "${1%.*}${suffix}.${1##*.}";
' find-sh {} \;
```

1. Please try to understand what this does.
2. Make sure you're paths don't include newline, otherwise the `awk` command will fail.
3. Remove the `echo` to perform the `mv` command if you're happy with the output.

Comment: It worked well mate. Thank you so much. Echo will show how the final image and I did use without an echo. And everything is perfectly renamed.  Can you explain what it does? Take your time.

Comment: *Make sure you're paths don't include newline, otherwise the awk command will fail.* where have I seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

With perl-rename (`sudo apt install rename`):

```
rename -n 's/(.+)\/(.+)\/.+\/[^.]+/$&-$2-$1/' ak/*/*/*.jpg
```

This command has to be started in `ak`’s parent directory. It `s`ubstitutes the path up until the extension dot with itself followed by the second and then the first directory name, each separated with hyphens. With `-n` it just prints what it wants to do, remove this option to perform the renaming.

#### Explanations

- `s/a/b/` – substitute `a` with `b`
- `(.+)\/` matches at least one character saving it in a group and a slash `/` which has to be escaped with a backslash `\`
- `.+\/` the same without saving it in a group – we don’t need the third directory again
- `[^.]+` matches at least one character which is not a dot – this matches any filename until the first dot (note that this means you can’t have any other dots in your filename than just the extension dot!)
- `$&-$2-$1` = the whole matched string `-` the second group `-` the first group

#### Example run

```bsh
$ tree ak
ak
├── adak
│   ├── cup-printing
│   │   └── Tshirt-printing.jpg
│   └── tshirt printing
│       └── Tshirt-printing.jpg
└── akhiok
    ├── cup-printing
    │   └── Tshirt-printing.jpg
    └── tshirt printing
        └── Tshirt-printing.jpg

6 directories, 4 files
$ rename -n 's/(.+)\/(.+)\/.+\/[^.]+/$&-$2-$1/' ak/*/*/*.jpg
rename(ak/adak/cup-printing/Tshirt-printing.jpg, ak/adak/cup-printing/Tshirt-printing-adak-ak.jpg)
rename(ak/adak/tshirt printing/Tshirt-printing.jpg, ak/adak/tshirt printing/Tshirt-printing-adak-ak.jpg)
rename(ak/akhiok/cup-printing/Tshirt-printing.jpg, ak/akhiok/cup-printing/Tshirt-printing-akhiok-ak.jpg)
rename(ak/akhiok/tshirt printing/Tshirt-printing.jpg, ak/akhiok/tshirt printing/Tshirt-printing-akhiok-ak.jpg)
$ ^-n^^     # ← this prints and runs the former command line without “-n”
rename  's/(.+)\/(.+)\/.+\/[^.]+/$&-$2-$1/' ak/*/*/*.jpg
$ tree ak
ak
├── adak
│   ├── cup-printing
│   │   └── Tshirt-printing-adak-ak.jpg
│   └── tshirt printing
│       └── Tshirt-printing-adak-ak.jpg
└── akhiok
    ├── cup-printing
    │   └── Tshirt-printing-akhiok-ak.jpg
    └── tshirt printing
        └── Tshirt-printing-akhiok-ak.jpg

6 directories, 4 files
```